# Firefox OS - Launch external link inside Firefox OS app and retrieve its content

Tags: firefox-os

I have a Firefox OS app in which I have opened an web page via mozbrowser attribute.

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
    mozbrowser=true 
    src="<some external link>"
</iframe>
```

How can we retrieve DOM content of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve DOM content via executeScript() method present in [Browser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Chrome/API/Browser_API/executeScript). It will run the script against the iframe and will allow you to do DOM computation tasks.

Note: The example mentioned in the document didn't worked but the syntax given below worked for me. The diff is  is passed as string.

iframe.executeScript('put_your_script_here', {origin: 'domain_name'});